# Bootstrap flexbox layout with nested columns and scrollbars

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am trying to achieve this layout:

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Flex Test</title>

    <script src="http://flex.test/js/app.js" defer></script>
    <link href="http://flex.test/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-directions text-primary"></i> Flex Test
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container h-100 py-4">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col h-100">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
                    <div class="border-bottom bg-success">
                        Lorem ipsum.
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg-primary flex-grow-1 mh-100 overflow-auto">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col h-100 bg-danger overflow-auto">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine if the red and blue boxes don't have content that is higher than the page height. As soon as the content is too long, it makes the page grow in height. I want the boxes to fill the page height, but if their contents are higher than the boxes I want scrollbars introduced.

I have no idea how to accomplish this via flexbox.

Comment: Can you add your css code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
<div class="container flex-grow-1 my-4">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 bg-info">
                <div class="border-bottom bg-success">
                    sort, search, post
                </div>
                <div class="bg-danger flex-grow-1 overflow-auto" style="height: 0;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod leo lacus, quis tempor lacus maximus vitae. Maecenas maximus consequat ultricies. Praesent eget scelerisque ipsum, at dictum mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel eleifend ligula. Ut varius non elit non faucibus. Morbi nec facilisis ligula. Donec sit amet consectetur nunc. Pellentesque id nisl ac neque pulvinar convallis. In ut purus vitae urna placerat lobortis.
                    Duis accumsan tortor non nisl sollicitudin commodo. Ut mollis sit amet dui nec scelerisque. Fusce at elit mauris. Ut risus velit, vehicula in lacus et, tempor pellentesque neque. Aenean dui massa, lobortis non euismod id, placerat sed sem.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod leo lacus, quis tempor lacus maximus vitae. Maecenas maximus consequat ultricies. Praesent eget scelerisque ipsum, at dictum mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel eleifend ligula. Ut varius non elit non faucibus. Morbi nec facilisis ligula. Donec sit amet consectetur nunc. Pellentesque id nisl ac neque pulvinar convallis. In ut purus vitae urna placerat lobortis.
                    Duis accumsan tortor non nisl sollicitudin commodo. Ut mollis sit amet dui nec scelerisque. Fusce at elit mauris. Ut risus velit, vehicula in lacus et, tempor pellentesque neque. Aenean dui massa, lobortis non euismod id, placerat sed sem.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod leo lacus, quis tempor lacus maximus vitae. Maecenas maximus consequat ultricies. Praesent eget scelerisque ipsum, at dictum mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel eleifend ligula. Ut varius non elit non faucibus. Morbi nec facilisis ligula. Donec sit amet consectetur nunc. Pellentesque id nisl ac neque pulvinar convallis. In ut purus vitae urna placerat lobortis.
                    Duis accumsan tortor non nisl sollicitudin commodo. Ut mollis sit amet dui nec scelerisque. Fusce at elit mauris. Ut risus velit, vehicula in lacus et, tempor pellentesque neque. Aenean dui massa, lobortis non euismod id, placerat sed sem.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 bg-info">
                <div class="bg-danger flex-grow-1 overflow-auto" style="height: 0;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod leo lacus, quis tempor lacus maximus vitae. Maecenas maximus consequat ultricies. Praesent eget scelerisque ipsum, at dictum mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel eleifend ligula. Ut varius non elit non faucibus. Morbi nec facilisis ligula. Donec sit amet consectetur nunc. Pellentesque id nisl ac neque pulvinar convallis. In ut purus vitae urna placerat lobortis.
                    Duis accumsan tortor non nisl sollicitudin commodo. Ut mollis sit amet dui nec scelerisque. Fusce at elit mauris. Ut risus velit, vehicula in lacus et, tempor pellentesque neque. Aenean dui massa, lobortis non euismod id, placerat sed sem.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod leo lacus, quis tempor lacus maximus vitae. Maecenas maximus consequat ultricies. Praesent eget scelerisque ipsum, at dictum mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel eleifend ligula. Ut varius non elit non faucibus. Morbi nec facilisis ligula. Donec sit amet consectetur nunc. Pellentesque id nisl ac neque pulvinar convallis. In ut purus vitae urna placerat lobortis.
                    Duis accumsan tortor non nisl sollicitudin commodo. Ut mollis sit amet dui nec scelerisque. Fusce at elit mauris. Ut risus velit, vehicula in lacus et, tempor pellentesque neque. Aenean dui massa, lobortis non euismod id, placerat sed sem.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If theres a better way of doing this I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check my solution. Here i provided a simple way to do this using flex layout.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.left .head {
  min-height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.left .content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.right {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="col-6 px-0">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="head"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet </div>
      <div class="content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 px-0">
    <div class="right">
      <div class="content">
        ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet repellendus quisquam placeat veritatis
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```